# Translating mouse coordinates to model coordinates in OpenGL when rotations are involved

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut, mouse-picking, qtopengl

In the Qt Forums I found [this question](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/49236/) and sparkled my curiosity.

I found a very simple example in Qt to display a cube and modified the cube logic to create a cube with a side length of 1 unit.

Then I tried to click on the model and show the coordinates of the area where I clicked.

When there are no rotations involved, it seems that the picking works fine. But! If I un-comment the rotations (or one of them) in `paintGL` I end up with "wrong" values.

For example:

- No rotations and click almost on the leftmost border of the cube: the `gluUnProject` method says that I clicked on the point `{ -0.49075, 0.234, 0.5 }`, which seems ok.

[image: Cube without rotations]

- Rotations enabled and click almost on the leftmost border of the cube: I receive the point `{ -0.501456, 0.157555, -0.482942 }`, which seems wrong. The `x` coordinate is off its range of `-0.5, 0.5`.

[image: Cube with the two rotations enabled]

I think the *coordinates transformation* is okay. I've been researching through Google and the people always use the same piece of code. Moreover, the color information of the pixel matches the color of the face where I clicked.

So, can anyone tell me why when a rotation is involved I get wrong coordinates? I think I'm failing in some basic 3D understanding, but I'm not able to realize where it is.

Here's the code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "GLCube.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    GLCube w;
    w.resize(800,600);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**GLCube.h**

```
#ifndef GLCUBE_H
#define GLCUBE_H

#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QGLWidget>

class GLCube : public QGLWidget{
  Q_OBJECT // must include this if you use Qt signals/slots
public:
    GLCube(QWidget *parent = NULL)
        : QGLWidget(parent) {
    }
protected:
    // Set up the rendering context, define display lists etc.:
   void initializeGL();
   // draw the scene:
   void paintGL();
   // setup viewport, projection etc.:
   void resizeGL (int width, int height);
   virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pme);
};

#endif
```

**GLCube.cpp:**

```
#include "GLCube.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "GL/glu.h"

namespace {
    float ver[8][3] =
    {
        { 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 },
        { -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 },
        { -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },
        { 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },
        { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 },
        { -0.5, 0.5, 0.5 },
        { -0.5, 0.5, -0.5 },
        { +0.5, 0.5, -0.5 }
    };
    GLfloat color[8][4] =
    {
        {0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0},
        {1.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0 },
        {1.0,1.0,0.0, 1.0 },
        {0.0,1.0,0.0, 1.0 },
        {0.0,0.0,1.0, 1.0 },
        {1.0,0.0,1.0, 1.0 },
        {1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0 },
        {0.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0 },
    };

    void quad(int a,int b,int c,int d, int col)
    {
        glPointSize( 5 );
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor4fv(color[1]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[a]);

            glColor4fv(color[2]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[b]);

            glColor4fv(color[3]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[c]);

            glColor4fv(color[4]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[d]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor4fv(color[1]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[a]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[b]);

            glColor4fv(color[1]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[b]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[c]);

            glColor4fv(color[1]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[c]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[d]);

            glColor4fv(color[1]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[d]);
            glVertex3fv(ver[a]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4fv(/*color[a]*/ color[col] );
        glVertex3fv(ver[a]);

    //    glColor3fv(color[b]);
        glVertex3fv(ver[b]);

    //    glColor3fv(color[c]);
        glVertex3fv(ver[c]);

    //    glColor3fv(color[d]);
        glVertex3fv(ver[d]);
        glEnd();
    }

    void colorcube()
    {
//        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
        quad( 3, 2, 1, 0, 1 ); // bottom
        quad( 7, 6, 5, 4, 2); // top
        quad( 6, 2, 1, 5, 3 ); // front
        quad( 7, 3, 0, 4, 5 ); // back
        quad( 7, 6, 2, 3, 6 ); // left
        quad( 4, 5, 1, 0, 7); // right
    }
}
/*
 * Sets up the OpenGL rendering context, defines display lists, etc.
 * Gets called once before the first time resizeGL() or paintGL() is called.
 */
void GLCube::initializeGL(){
    //activate the depth buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}


/*
 *  Sets up the OpenGL viewport, projection, etc. Gets called whenever the widget has been resized
 *  (and also when it is shown for the first time because all newly created widgets get a resize event automatically).
 */
void GLCube::resizeGL (int width, int height){
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height );
    /* create viewing cone with near and far clipping planes */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 15.0, 30.0);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}

/*
 * Renders the OpenGL scene. Gets called whenever the widget needs to be updated.
 */
void GLCube::paintGL(){

    //delete color and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-20.0f); //move along z-axis
        glRotatef(30.0,0.0,1.0,0.0); //rotate 30 degress around y-axis
        glRotatef(15.0,1.0,0.0,0.0); //rotate 15 degress around x-axis

    colorcube();
//    originalcube();
}

void GLCube::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pme) {
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
    glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

    const int x = pme->x();
    const int y = viewport[3] - pme->y();

    qDebug() << "HERE: " << x << y;

    GLfloat color[4];
    glReadPixels( x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, color);
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    std::cout << "RETRIEVED COLOR:" << color[0] << ", " << color[1] << ", " << color[2] << ", " << color[3] << std::endl;
    printf( "\tERROR: %s (Code: %u)\n", gluErrorString(error), error );
    if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) throw;

    GLdouble depthScale;
    glGetDoublev( GL_DEPTH_SCALE, &depthScale );
    std::cout << "DEPTH SCALE: " << depthScale << std::endl;
    GLfloat z;
    glReadPixels( x, y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z );
    error = glGetError();
    std::cout << "X: " << x << ", Y: " << y  << ", RETRIEVED Z: " << z << std::endl;
    printf( "\tERROR: %s (Code: %u)\n", gluErrorString(error), error );
    if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) throw;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;
    GLint result;
    result = gluUnProject( x, y, z, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
    error = glGetError();
    std::cout << "3D point with POS: " << posX << " " << posY << " " << posZ << std::endl;
    printf( "\tERROR: %s (Code: %u)\n", gluErrorString(error), error );
    std::cout << "\tglUnProject: " << (( GL_FALSE == result ) ? "FALSE" : "TRUE") << std::endl;
    if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) throw;
}
```

**NOTE:**

I'm running this in Windows 8.1 64 bit, Qt 4.8 and MinGW.

Also, both `glReadPixels` and `gluUnProject` exit without errors (ERROR CODE = `GL_NO_ERROR` )

And `glut` is not available. Only what `OpenGL`, `QtOpenGL` and/or `glu` offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really wrong, you are reading the depth buffer to figure out the window-space Z value to use for reverse projection.

The problem is that there is limited precision available in the depth buffer, and that introduces a bit of inaccuracy. In reality you cannot expect the range of unprojected values to be perfectly [**-0.5**,**0.5**]. You are going to have to introduce a small epsilon here, so your effective range would then be something like [**-0.5015**,**0.5015**].

You could probably lessen the impact by increasing the precision of your depth buffer and/or decreasing the range between the near and far clip planes. The depth buffer is generally 24-bit fixed-point by default, but a 32-bit fixed-point or floating-point depth buffer might slightly improve your situation. However, you are never going to completely eliminate this problem.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I never thought about the innacuracy. I'll try your suggestion!

Comment: Also, I noted that when clicking in the rim of the model, I get sensible values (with the epsilon, as you kindly explained). But if I click near the rim, but on the outside, in the black bacground, I get something like `4.66933, -1.30734, -8.8131`. Is there a way to "disable" this or do I have to check the returned point and see if it has sensible bounds?

Comment: @AdriC.S.: What's happening there is that you're reading a cleared part of the depth buffer. The default clear depth is **1.0**. Since it is very unlikely that you will ever click on something with a depth exactly equal to **1.0** (this would be something that lies _exactly_ on the far clipping plane), you can probably just assume that if you read back **1.0** for the depth that there was nothing under the cursor.